# Most efficient way to edit Django settings file in Vim

Tags: django, sqlite, vim

What is the most efficient way (i.e., the fewest number of keystrokes) to edit the default Django settings file in Vim to use SQLite?

The bare settings file looks like this:

```
# Django settings for mysite project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
...
```

...and I want it to look like this:

```
# Django settings for mysite project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'local.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
...
```

I know this is a trivial question, but I'm trying to get more efficient with Vim, so I'm curious if others have quicker approaches to this repetitive task.

Comment: Is vim the only option? Can you try using nano?

Comment: (1) This question is specifically about Vim. (2) I'd be surprised if Nano were more efficient than Vim in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this won't win [Vim Golf](http://vimgolf.com/), but here's how I'd do it. Starting in normal mode:

```
:%s/backends./backends.sqlite3/ <Enter>
/NAME <Enter>
2f'
i local.db
```

That is: search for backends. through the whole buffer, replace the first instance with backends.sqlite3. Then, search for NAME and move the cursor to the first instance found. Then, search forward on the current line for the second occurrence of ' (single quote). Enter insert mode. Type out local.db

**Update**

In the interest of maximizing efficiency and using the suggestion in the comments, here's a slightly shortened version that still uses the same approach:

```
:%s/ends./&sqlite3/ <Enter>
/NAM <Enter>
2f'
i local.db
```

I was going to use `/NA` until I noticed that MANAGER shows up before NAME. Vim Golf score for this approach: 38.

Comment: I look forward to even better answers, so that I can improve my Vim skills too.

Comment: Finally, if you're curious, I mark my vim golf score for this as 51. Could be cut down if you reduced the length of search strings to the minimum unique strings to guarantee reaching the position desired.

Comment: For vim golf, you could reduce the first line to `:%s/backends./&sqlite3/<CR>` :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the & in s// bodies.